# How do I extract user details for Bloomberg Desktop API connection?

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

If you type `IAM <GO>` in the terminal you'll be shown the UserID, UUID, CLID etc.

Is it possible to extract this information through blpapi when using the Desktop API to connect via BBComm?  I've seen references to `Identity` and populating that by sending an `AuthorizationRequest` but it appears that's only relevant for SAPI/B-PIPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "SID report" which is provide together with monthly invoices from Bloomberg which contains the UUIDs for users - this can be used to look up existing users but when setting up a brand new account you have to manually copy this information out of the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge and after asking a couple of Bloomberg reps - this isn't possible. The best work around which I've found is: each user creates an EQS screen called their UUID. Add some filtering which causes this screening to return nothing. Then the application, upon start up, requests all possible UUIDs as EQS screens and stops when it doesn't get back an error - that's the UUID.

This is a dirty, dirty hack and, granted, this only works if you have few distinct users using your system. You don't want to ask may users to create such a screen and probably don't want to iterate over thousands of EQS screen names.