# How to get Bloomberg UUID in Excel

Tags: excel, bloomberg

In an Excel sheet I need to get the UUID of the user currently logged in on the terminal. I'm not optimistic that this can be done as blpapi doesn't have this functionality ([How do I extract user details for Bloomberg Desktop API connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955953/how-do-i-extract-user-details-for-bloomberg-desktop-api-connection)). I was hoping that the @BSettings function would give this but this is not the case, it only gives info on the version of the Excel plugin

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using the Excel API. That is designed for retrieving market data, and information that pertains to that process.

If you want the UUID, you can run `IAM<GO>` on the terminal. There may be other places locally that Bloomberg stores UUID and other such information but that is not intended for use by end users so YMMV.